# ASP.NET Core - configure HTTP logging fields through configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

In my ASP.NET Core 8.0-preview startup, I'm using and configuring `HttpLogging` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.Request | HttpLoggingFields.Response;
});
```

Is it possible to configure the `LoggingFields` property via configuration (e.g. in `appsettings.json`) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. `LoggingFields` is an enum flag, If you wanna read options via `appsetting.json`, you need to read property from `appsetting.json` first then convert it to `LoggingFields` enum options.

For example, I use

```
logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestPath | HttpLoggingFields.RequestMethod;
```

to log request path and method

[image]

Now if wanna configure in `appsetting.json`, I can

```
"MySettings": {
    "EnumFlagValue": "RequestPath,RequestMethod"
  }

builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(x =>
{
    var value = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings:EnumFlagValue").Value;
    var enumFlagValues = value.Split(',').Select(fieldName => Enum.Parse<HttpLoggingFields>(fieldName)).Aggregate((fields, field) => fields | field);
    x.LoggingFields = enumFlagValues;
});
```

[image]

In my opinion, even you can configure it via `appsetting.json`, I still think use enum options directly is more convenient and faster then configure via `appsetting.json`.

Comment: thanks! can you explain this? "I still think use enum options directly is more convenient and faster then configure via appsetting.json" My whole point about using configuration instead of doing it in code is to change it without rebuild/redeployment

Comment: Yes, your point is 100% correct, If user can read LoggingFields 's options from `appsetting.json`, they don't need to rebuild/redeployment every time when change options. In my opinion, when I use `httpLogging`, I will not change the options very often, So I will write in code directly. Luckily, we can not only configure it in code, but also configure it in appsetting.json file